# can a compiler of a language L be implemented in the same language L ?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, programming-languages

I know many languages that compilers are implemented in the same language:
   - The C# Roslyn Compiler is implemented in C#
   - The F# Compiler is implemented in F#

Now, I think that is possible for example implement the compiler of C# 6.0 in C# 5.0

Then my question is about the same version of the language, that is:

```
can a compiler of a language L be implemented in the same language L ?
```

I ask this because I hear that typescript compiler is implemented in typescript, but
there are no previous version of the typescript language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not necessarily easy to find if you don't know the name, but everything you want to know should be at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: @Eric If that answer worked for you, it's good etiquette to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The term is known as bootstrapping:

[Bootstrapping (compilers): Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29)